# Can you add variables inside "cout"

Tags: c++, cout

I'm new to C++, on the chapter 2 quiz of LearnCpp.com.  I'm stuck and have a question.  Can you add variables inside a std::cout statement?  For example:

The program will not display my answer.  The program ends as soon as the user presses enter after inputting the values.  Thanks for your help ahead of time.

EDIT: Sorry for not posting the entire code.  I'm also new to forums.  I added the `()` like someone suggested.  When I ran the program I think I saw it display the answer for a split second and it doesn't show that `Press any key to continue. . .`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
double first_value;
double second_value;
char user_operator;

std::cout << "Enter a double value: ";
std::cin >> first_value;
std::cout << "Enter a second double value: ";
std::cin >> second_value;
std::cout << "Enter one of the following (+, -, *, /): ";
std::cin >> user_operator;

if (user_operator == 43 || user_operator == 45\
    || user_operator == 42 || user_operator == 47)
    switch (user_operator)
    {
        case 43:
            std::cout << "  " << (first_value + second_value) << "\n";
            break;
        case 45:
            std::cout << "  " << (first_value - second_value) << "\n";
            break;
        case 42:
            std::cout << "  " << (first_value * second_value) << "\n";
            break;
        case 47:
            std::cout << "  " << (first_value / second_value) << "\n";
            break;
    }
else std::cout << "Please enter a valid operator.";

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Something went wrong when you tried to isolate your actual issue. Perhaps none of the `case`s were taken.

Comment: What is the `switch` statement? That's probably the source of the problem.   Note: You can `cout` your expression because `<<` has lower precedence than arithmetic operators ( + - * ./ ). Even if it didn't you could put the expression in parentheses.

Comment: _@marcellatwin_ Please don't post bogus code, but a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem you face.

Comment: Show us more of the code, preferably entirely (if it is not too big). Particularly, you didn't show how you read user's input and what is `switch` of those `case`s. Anyway, it is better to enclose  `(first_value + second_value)` into parentheses

Comment: This is a wild guess. But does adding the lines char ch; std::cin >> ch; At the end of your program fix the issue?

Comment: _@marcellatwin_ To clarify more `Case 42` isn't valid c++ syntax, neither `...` is. Put efforts in your question please. Come on, do it right, edit that shit, to get concise answers.

Comment: i assume that you are using VC++ when your console shows the result for split second, to fix it, add `std::cin.ignore()` at end of `main()`. also remove the if statement it doesn't make sense here you already using `switch` . here fixed example: http://cpp.sh/8gfcr

Comment: Sorry to hear you're not happy with your experience here - it does happen. People either reassess their expectations of how to ask questions and what questions are acceptable, or they decide that this site is not for them. Either are okay! If you really wish to complain you are free to do so on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but it is probably not worth it...

Comment: ... if you want to do some pair programming debugging (i.e. with people eliciting new bits of information from you piecemeal, instead of adding all necessary information to the question) then this site is not a great fit for that.

Comment: Finally, criticism != bashing here. It does feel like a baptism of fire, to be sure, but don't worry about being a beginner. Just mentally summarise all of the good feedback you've received on this thread, filter out anything that you didn't find helpful, and ask another question. That one, I am sure, will be better!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can perform operations within a chain of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` calls. You just need to obey [operator precedence](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and put parenthesis (`()`) around the expression to disambiguate in case it's necessary.

Here's a fixed [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06555f1df5c9147f).